# Linq Overlapped date range checking in single collection

Tags: c#, linq

```
Class TimeRange{
  private DateTime StartDate{get; set;}
  private DateTime EndDate{get; set;}
}

List<TimeRange> TimeRangeList = new List<TimeRange>(){
  new TimeRange(){StartDate = new DateTime(2050, 1, 1), 
                    EndDate = new DateTime(2050, 1, 10)},
  new TimeRange(){StartDate = new DateTime(2050, 2, 1), 
                    EndDate = new DateTime(2050, 2, 10)},
  //This item will triggered the overlap validation failed
  new TimeRange(){StartDate = new DateTime(2050, 1, 5),
                    EndDate = new DateTime(2050, 1, 9)},
                              },
}
```

so after I checked out the [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175466/date-range-overlap-issue-in-linq), I still can't figured out the algorithm of checking the overlapped date range.

This is quite simple in SQL, according to [Checking for date overlap across multiple date range objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033397/checking-for-date-overlap-across-multiple-date-range-objects)

I just need to compare two date range like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.StartDate < 'endCheckDate'
AND Table1.EndDate > 'startCheckDate'
```

I found it is difficult to do in Linq, how do we compare all items in one collection within? of cause we can use foreach in just loop the collection just like comparing two list, but how is it work in select?

actually I'm doing something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < TimeRangeList .Count(); ++i)
{
        var item = TimeRangeList[i];                    
        for (int y = i + 1; y < TimeRangeList.Count(); ++y)
        {
                var item2 = TimeRangeList[y];

                if (IsOverLapped(item, item2))
                {
                    // this is overlapped
                };
        }
}

private bool IsOverLapped(dynamic firstObj, dynamic secondObj)
{
        return secondObj.StartDate <= firstObj.EndDate && firstObj.StartDate <= secondObj.EndDate;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do without looping?

so my questions is how do we compare one single list for each items itself by linq?

Comment: The SQL checks for a fixed start/end period. It's not clear what you want to do in Linq, Group the items?

Comment: Why you don't provide compiling code if you already provide a sample list? For instance, there is no DateTime constructor that takes a string.

Comment: You could use this TimePeriod lib: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET It also has a TimeRange class and methods like OverlapsWith or IntersectsWith.

Comment: @bommelding sorry for confusing, I'm actually doing ModelState.AddModelError() if the overlapped is happening. It is simply return a boolean in this case. I update my sample list, assuming there must be a fixed time for checking, just I'm should sure how it work in linq

Comment: @bommelding TimeRangeList.Any(
/* datetime overlapped checking*/
);

I'm putting it into a rule for [validation](https://fluentvalidation.net/custom-validators.html)

Comment: @bommelding why did you delete your comment? I just wanna say it passed all the scenario I have tested, and that should be the answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

A simple brute force idea:

```
bool overlap = TimeRangeList
    .Any(r => TimeRangeList
         .Where(q => q != r)             
         .Any(q => q.EndDate >= r.StartDate && q.StartDate <= r.EndDate) );
```

Comment: works like a charm! but how does this linq work? let me test a bit more, I really appreciate with your help

Comment: Is there _any_ element that has an overlap with _any_ _other_ element? The _other_ part is realised by `q != r`.

Comment: But the last condition was of course not correct yet, edited now.

Answer (score 0):

If I look at your SQLcode, it seems that you have a `Table1` object which is a sequence of similar objects, let's say of class `Table1Row`. Every `Table1Row` has at least two DateTime properties, a `StartDate` and an `EndDate`. Furthermore you have two DateTime objects: `startCheckDate` and `endCheckDate`.

You want to count all elements in your `Table1` that have a `StartDate` smaller than `startCheckDate` and an `EndDate` larger than `endCheckDate`

Written as an extension function of IQueryable:

```
public static int CountOverlapping(this IQueryable<Table1Row> table1,
    DateTime startCheckDate,
    DateTime endCheckDate)
{
    return table1
        .Where (row => row.StartDate < startCheckDate && row.EndDate > endCheckDate)
        .Count();
}
```

Usage:

```
DateTime startCheckDate = ...
DateTime endCheckDate = ...
IQueryable<Table1Row> table1 = ...
int nrOfOverlapping = table1.CountOverlapping(startCheckDate, endCheckDate);
```

Simple comme bonjour?

Comment: thanks for that,  just I'm looking for a method to ask the list to compare itself by  the time properties, it is dynamic and generic. In your provided method, one might be looping twice, pretending it have two lists and call the method, and that's not I really want to.

Comment: actually @bommelding posted his idea, that I think should be the accurate answer, however seems he just deleted the answer, will give him the credit if he rewind it.

Comment: Why do you think that a Where followed by a Count needs to enumerate twice?

Comment: Sorry if I confuse you in my topic. But in this case, it have to be a comparison of each those items themselves through the list, but not a given date range. so we don,t input them as parameters. Your example assume I have one input date as checking point.